# How can you tell if an HTML dropdown is displaying the list of options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to determine if a given drop down is currently active and displaying it's list of options?

I am currently binding to the mousedown event of the dropdown and populating the options when the user clicks on it. Unfortunately the mousedown event fires when the user selects the option as well.

If I can determine if the drop down is already displaying it's options, then I can skip populating the options.

Comment: Possibly stupid question: why can't you populate the options beforehand? It might take a while for the action to finish and the user expects the dropdown to open when clicked...

Comment: The drop down is used to filter a table and I only want to display the values which are currently in the table. Since there are multiple drop down filters, each corresponding to a different column I need to populate them on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you if the select element has options in it

In javascript

```
document.getElementById("mySelectElementId").options.length
```

In JQuery

```
$("#mySelectElementId")[0].options.length
```

---

**Edited:**
   OK instead of using the mousedown event try using the focus event on the select element.  This will also ensure that you populate the control properly when a user uses tab to get to the select element.

Comment: In my case, that will not work, since the drop down might already have values in it. The options get loaded everytime the user clicks on the drop down.

Comment: @Ross Goddard...Sounds like you really want to use the focus event not the mouse down event